# How to load a file located in core/includes?

Tags: 8

I'd like to execute PHP code that requires functions available in the includes files of core located in `core/includes`.

I found [`ModuleHandler()->loadInclude()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ModuleHandler.php/function/ModuleHandler%3A%3AloadInclude/8.7.x) and [`module_load_include()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/8.7.x) but I am afraid this 2 options can load files from *core/modules* directory only, according to the doc, but may be I misinterpreted it:

> Loads a module include file.

For example if I execute:

```php
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->loadInclude('core', 'inc', 'install');
drupal_rewrite_settings(); // the func that I want located in install.inc
```

I get:

```
Call to undefined function drupal_rewrite_settings()
```

which means `install.inc` has not been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a good old fashioned `include_once` (or `require_once`):

```
include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/core/includes/install.inc';
```

Core uses the same method any time it needs to source a file in core/includes. Case in point, [`ModuleHandler::loadInclude`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ModuleHandler.php/function/ModuleHandler%3A%3AloadInclude/8.7.x) itself does exactly that if the file extension provided is "install":

```
public function loadInclude($module, $type, $name = NULL) {
  if ($type == 'install') {
    // Make sure the installation API is available
    include_once $this->root . '/core/includes/install.inc';
  }

  ...
```